# Why is the difference in running time so long between these two codes?

Tags: c++

For both codes l is initially 1 , all variables except the array are long long , array is global int of size N. N is to the order of 10^6. But code 1 exceeds time limit of 5 seconds but code 2 runs in milliseconds. The only difference is in the last line. a,b,c are integer variables less than 50.

Compiler used :- g++

test case :-
3000000 50 50 50 1 (N,a,b,c,l)

Code 1:-

```
for(i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
        j=l;
        k=(j*j)%1000000;
        k=(a*k)%1000000;
        j=(b*j)%1000000;
        l=(j+k+c)%1000000;


        x=(int)l;
        ar[i]=x;
    }
```

Code 2:-

```
for(i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
        j=l;
        k=(j*j)%1000000;
        k=(a*k)%1000000;
        j=(b*j)%1000000;
        l=(j+k+c)%1000000;


        x=(int)l;
        ar[i]=1;
    }
```

Comment: Is these timings an average for a number of runs or just a one off?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Did you enable optimization?

Comment: You should post a test-case. There are too many unknowns to reach any meaningful conclusions.

Comment: @OMGtechy g++ compiler , yes optimization is enabled.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion

Comment: @HansPassant :- thanks for that but what makes code 1 exceed 5 seconds due to just that ar[i]=l; statement?

Comment: I believe Avt's answer is correct. I mean in the second case all of your calculation in the loop is optimized out because you do not use the result of the calculation.

Comment: @AnmolSood, Try to disable optimisation and check again.

Comment: I assume in both cases you do not use the variable l after the loop. What happens if you cout l?

Comment: @drescherjm :- runtime error in both cases if I print l. Also when I make the array ar local(instead of global) , the time difference is not significant in both cases but runtime error when I print l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is compiler's optimisation. Probably second code is just replaced with

```
for(i=1;i<N;i++)
{
    ar[i]=1;
}
```

Comment: May not even bother to compute `l`